# Fuzzy texture in soildworks

Tags: solidworks, 3d-printing, carbon-fiber

Is there a way to add a "fuzzy" texture to a body in solidworks?

Something like this:
[image]

The purpose - to 3d print a body with a fuzzy surface to get better bonding

Any other ideas to improve the bonding surface will be great (fiberglass -> epoxy -> 3d printed stuff (PLA / PETG not sure which one to use yet)

(I prefer to do it in solidworks and not add the fuzzy feature in Cura)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

This has been a feature since 2019 http://help.solidworks.com/2019/english/solidworks/sldworks/c_3d_textures.htm

The only 'downside' is that the output is a mesh body not BREP, but this isn't an issue in its intended use case of 3D print files. For rendering you would just bump map the smooth surface.

Comment: Thanks! I saw that but didn't find a way to do something so fine, almost making the print surface poreuse, like paper towel surface

Comment: You just need to find the right bump map image, and scale its size and bump height appropriately for what you need.